# Surjectivity of differential operator between Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Me and a friend of mine are working on the following exercise: let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$, characterize the sets: 
$$ X=\{ D_{x_i} u : u \in L^2(\Omega) ; \ i=1, \dots n \} \qquad Y=\{ D_{x_i x_j} v : v \in H^1(\Omega); \ i,j=1, \dots n \}$$

We started with the case $n=1$ and $\Omega=(0,1) $ for simplicity and concluded that $X=Y=H^{-1}(0,1)$ essentially through the following steps (here $D(A)$ is a short notation to indicate the set of weak derivatives of functions of $A$):

(i) $D(\mathcal{D}(0,1))=\{ \phi \in \mathcal{D}(0,1) : \int_{[0,1]} \phi =0 \}$

(ii) $ D(H^1_0(0,1))=\{ f \in L^2(0,1) : \int_{[0,1]} f = 0 \}$

(iii) $ D(H^1(0,1))= L^2(0,1) $

(iv) $D(L^2(0,1))= H^{-1}(0,1)$

where we mostly used elementary techniques (density results, classical inequalities...). Later on we discovered that (iii) may be proved very easily using FCT and the characterization $H^1(0,1)=\{ u \in AC([0,1]) : u' \in L^2(0,1) \}$.

We are asking ourselves if this result is actually true and if it can be generalized to higher dimensions without being forced to complicated and technical proofs.

Comment: By $H^{-1}(0,1)$ do you mean the dual of $H^1(0,1)$ or of $H_0^1(0,1)$?

Comment: The dual of $H^{1}_0$!